# Include Rows with Zero Count() Values

Tags: mysql, graph, count, relational-database, relation

I'm designing a tag-based pseudo-category system.

There I have two tables - connection and keyword.
'keyword' defines categories and 'connection' is an adjacency list.

When a category is clicked, the view shows subcategories.

```
SELECT kw.kw_id, kw.kw_name, kw.kw_desc
FROM keyword AS kw, connection AS conn
WHERE conn.kw1id = :kw1 AND conn.kw2id = kw.kw_id
```

This works just fine, but now I want to sort those subcategories by the number of their children.

```
SELECT  child.id AS child_id, keyword.kw_name AS child_name, keyword.kw_desc AS child_desc,
            COUNT(r1.conn_id) AS out_degree
FROM keyword
INNER JOIN connection AS r1 ON r1.kw1id = keyword.kw_id
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT kw2id AS id
    FROM connection AS conn
    WHERE conn.kw1id = [ID_CLICKED]
) AS child ON child.id = r1.kw1id

GROUP BY r1.kw1id

ORDER BY out_degree DESC
```

But this returns only categories with >0 children. How do I include leaf nodes?

Comment: so to clarify, starting with a node [ID_CLICKED], you want to list the children, with a count of the grand-children? also `connection.kw1id` is a parent of `connection.kw2id` - is that correct?

Comment: and you want to list all the children, even those with no children themselves?

Comment: Yes. Grandchildren it is.

Comment: in that case I'm pretty confident my latest query gives you what you are after... by the way is can your tags have multiple parents? if so I'll post an update to avoid double counting

Comment: Yes, because this is not really a hierarchical tree, but only a tree representation of a graph, it is possible that some nodes have multiple parents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply replace the `INNER` with `LEFT` ought to do it...

by the way you don't really need that subquery

its hard to be sure, but from your description I think something like this is what you want??

```
 SELECT  k.id AS child_id,   
         k.kw_name AS child_name,  
         k.kw_desc AS child_desc,
         COUNT(rb.conn_id) AS out_degree
 FROM connection AS ra 
 LEFT JOIN keyword As k ON ra.kw2id = k.id AND ra.reltype = 'blah'
 LEFT JOIN connection As rb ON rb.kw1id = k.id AND rb.reltype = 'blah'
 WHERE ra.kw1id = [ID_CLICKED]
 GROUP BY k.id 
 ORDER BY out_degree DESC
```

This should count the children of the children of [ID_CLICKED] and should still include the childless

To avoid multiple counting, change this:

```
COUNT(rb.conn_id) AS out_degree
```

to

```
COUNT(distinct rb.kw2id) AS out_degree
```

so each grand child only gets counted once

Comment: The subquery inside JOIN works perfectly when separated from the code outside, listing every end-node (kw2) from front-node [ID_CLICKED]. But when put inside JOIN, it just ignores all items with 0 out_degree.

Comment: This works perfect for unlabeled graph but what if there is additional  'relation_type' column in table 'connection'? I omitted it just to simplify the problem but now I can't figure out where to put WHERE clause (eg, WHERE rel_type = 1).

Comment: edited my answer - it could go either in the `join` or the `where` clause - I dont think it matters - although sql optimizers sometimes do funny things and I guess some engines may use/not use an index if you put it in different places - for a smart optimizer it shouldnt make any difference - generally mysql is pretty smart :-)

Comment: I'm assuming you want rel type filters for both conncection joins, so just added them

Comment: AND ra.reltype = 'blah' doesn't take effect. AND rb.reltype = 'blah' excludes entries with out_degree of 0. Now I'm back to the beginning.

Comment: Doh you'll need to put the clauses in the join because is a left join.  Doh sorry

Answer (score 0):

as something closer to your original query - does this work? (note the 3 **changes**)

```
SELECT  child.id AS child_id, keyword.kw_name AS child_name, keyword.kw_desc AS child_desc,
            COUNT(r1.conn_id) AS out_degree
FROM keyword
**LEFT** JOIN connection AS r1 ON **r1.kw2id** = keyword.kw_id
**LEFT** JOIN (
    SELECT kw2id AS id
    FROM connection AS conn
    WHERE conn.kw1id = [ID_CLICKED]
) AS child ON child.id = r1.kw1id
GROUP BY r1.kw1id
ORDER BY out_degree DESC
```

yeah I know, two answers to one question... but they're different answers :-)